# ¿Por que me dice cannot find symbol en SEVERE?

Tags: java, mysql

Estoy haciendo mi primer proyecto con Netbeans y MySQL en Java. Mi problema surge cuando quiero consultar datos desde un `JTable`.

```
package ventanas;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Statement;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.lang.System.Logger.Level;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.sql.*;
import java.sql.SQLException;


public class BuscarProductos extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    { 
   initComponents();
   mostrarTabla();
} 

    void mostrartabla(){
        DefaultTableModel modelo = new  DefaultTableModel();
        modelo.addColumn("Id");
        modelo.addColumn("Nombre");
        modelo.addColumn("Precio");
        modelo.addColumn("Descripcion");
        modelo.addColumn("Vencimiento");
        modelo.addColumn("Laboratorio");
        modelo.addColumn("Cantidad");
        tabladatos.setModel(modelo);

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM productos";

        String datos[] = new String [7];
        Statement st;
        try {
             st = ConexionBD.createStatements(); 
              ResultSet rs= st.executeQuery(sql);
              while(rs.next()){
                  datos[0]=rs.getString(1);
                  datos[1]=rs.getString(2);
                  datos[2]=rs.getString(3);
                  datos[3]=rs.getString(4);
                  datos[4]=rs.getString(5);
                  datos[5]=rs.getString(6);
                  datos[6]=rs.getString(7);
                  modelo.addRow(datos);

        }
              tabladatos.setModel(modelo);

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(BuscarProductos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

        }

    }
```

Me tira este error:

```
cannot find symbol
Logger.getLogger(BuscarProductos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
symbol:   variable SEVERE
location: class Level
```

Si pudieran darme una mano seria de gran ayuda, un saludo!

Comment: ¿No te funciona con `import java.util.logging.Level;`? (Tienes que quitar el otro import: `import java.lang.System.Logger.Level;`)

Comment: Gracias eso soluciono el error en SEVERE, pero ahora me sale el mismo error en  cannot find symbol
            Logger.getLogger(BuscarProductos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  symbol:   method getLogger(String)
  location: interface Logger

Comment: Asegurate que solo tienes estos para Level y Logger: `import java.util.logging.Level;`
`import java.util.logging.Logger;`. Si usas eclipse pulsa ctrl+shift+o para organizarte los imports y ahorrarte estos dolores de cabeza. Con netbeans hay un equivalente pero no me acuerdo de la combinación de teclas. Mira una opción que sea "Organize Imports..."

Comment: Uff muchas gracias por tu ayuda amigo, estuve toda la mañana como loco buscando una solución. Estaba haciendo cualquier cosa con los import jaja

Answer (score 1):

no uses la libreria `import java.lang.System.Logger.Level;`
ya que solo te falta la libreria `import java.util.logging.Level;`
Espero te sirva a mi me funciono.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que estas importando una librería incorrecta. Prueba a importar esta librería:

```
import java.lang.System.Logger.Level;
```

en vez de `java.util.logging.Level`

Comment: Me sigue apareciendo el mismo error :(